# How to properly create Expression with Any statement?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I wanted to ask how to properly create Expression for:

```cs
x => x.AnotherEntities.Any(y => y.AnotherProp == "something")
```

I've checked a lot of examples and read a lot of information about Expressions to understand why I'm getting errors, but still nothing.

Currently I'm trying:

```cs
source = MyFunction(x => x.AnotherEntities, y => y.AnotherProp, "something", source);
```

```cs
private IQueryable<MyEntity> MyFunction<T>(Expression<Func<MyEntity, List<T>>> prop,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> subProp,
    string value,
    IQueryable<MyEntity> source)
{
    var method = typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethods()
        .FirstOrDefault(method => method.Name == "Any" 
            && method.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

    var expression = Expression.Equal(subProp.Body, Expression.Constant(value));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, subProp.Parameters);

    return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<MyEntity, bool>>
    (
        body: Expression.Call
        (
            null, method, lambda
        ),
        parameters: prop.Parameters
    ));
}
```

```cs
public class MyEntity {
    public List<AnotherEntity> AnotherEntities { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherEntity {
    public string AnotherProp { get; set; }
}
```

Getting exception:

> ArgumentException Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Any[AnotherEntity](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication.Models.AnotherEntity], System.Func`2[WebApplication.Models.AnotherEntity,System.Boolean])'
>   Parameter name: method

Comment: Why do you need this? `MyFunction(x => x.AnotherEntities, y => y.AnotherProp, "something", source)` This statement implies that you have all the necessary values at compile-time to write this expression yourself without building it.

Comment: ` body: Expression.Call(null, method, lambda),` you can't call a method on null?

Comment: Hi, @AvinKavish, I need this because have lots of properties in models. When creating LINQ statement for any of property I prefer to use one generic function instead of creating function per property. Another way it's dynamic filtering/sorting by string, but I'm confused on this approach because of loosing strongly typed bind-model.

Comment: @AvinKavish If I'm understanding right, we need specify null if we have a static method? Anyway if I'll do ` body: Expression.Call(prop.Body, method, lambda) ` I'll get exception: "Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.".

Comment: That's right my bad, you are calling an extension method. Okay, so since it's a static method you need to pass the object you want to call it on as an argument.

Comment: I'm not sure how to construct this expression but the problem is that `Expression.Call` is not getting the instance you want to call the `Any()` method on. you have to pass it as the first argument after `method` and before `lambda`

Comment: @AvinKavish You are precisely right, just tested, everything works as expected. Sorry for my incomprehension, I'm new to Expressions totally. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I am the author of the library in question.)

I would suggest using [ExpressionTreeToString](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString), available as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExpressionTreeToString/):

The following code:

```
Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> expr = x => x.AnotherEntities.Any(y => y.AnotherProp == "something");
Console.WriteLine(
    expr.ToString("Factory methods")
);
```

prints:

```
// using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

Lambda(
    Call(
        typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Any"),
        MakeMemberAccess(x,
            typeof(MyEntity).GetProperty("AnotherEntities")
        ),
        Lambda(
            Equal(
                MakeMemberAccess(y,
                    typeof(AnotherEntity).GetProperty("AnotherProp")
                ),
                Constant("something")
            ),
            var y = Parameter(
                typeof(AnotherEntity),
                "y"
            )
        )
    ),
    var x = Parameter(
        typeof(MyEntity),
        "x"
    )
)
```

which shows that `Call` in this instance needs three parameters:

1. the method
2. the object which is passed as the first parameter of the method -- the member access of `AnotherEntities` on the instance of `MyEntity`
3. the lambda expression

You're not passing in the second argument.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Your library is gorgeous, @Zev. I'll try to use it :)